# Android Dialog - how to get value for windowMinWidthMajor/windowMinWidthMinor

Tags: android, themes, getattr

I define my theme this way

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</style>
```

I have native c++ activity in which I want set correct width for my windows based on windowMinWidthMajor/windowMinWidthMinor. I tried to get these values from context.getTheme() this way in constructor:

```
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    Resources.Theme theme = getTheme();
    theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.windowMinWidthMajor, typedValue, true);
    int percentageValue = typedValue.data;
```

However it always returns 0. How can I obtain correct values ?